# VBA Array copy several values at once

Tags: arrays, vba

Is it possible to copy a bunch of values from a VBA array to another array, without a loop?

Something like DestArray(4:7)=OrigArray(8:11)

Comment: If they are virtual arrays it does not take that much time to iterate, the calculations are quick even for large arrays.  It is when you constantly refer to the worksheet that the loops slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as the array you are not copying *in to* is not dimensioned from the start and is of the same type.

I.e: -

`Dim DestinationArray(1) As string` will cause an error but `Dim DestinationArray() As string` will not.

`Dim DestinationArray() As Long` will cause an error if the source is not also `Long`

```
Public Sub test()
Dim Array1(1) As String
Dim Array2() As String

Array1(0) = "Hello"
Array1(1) = "World!"

Array2() = Array1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but not what I asked for. I asked about copying a specific bunch of values, not whole arrays.